# Whats the deal with foreign websites mirroring YouTube videos and comments 1:1?

Tags: youtube

Examples:
https://azchart.info/
https://trshow.info/

I don't speak the language there, but it is quite obvious the site, or a user on it, is copying YouTube videos, and somehow even the comments are present in the comment section? It doesn't seem to be some kind of embedded YouTube site - I can't think of how they copy all the comments with names and avatars.

The reason I am asking this is because they copied a video where I was commenting years ago, and back then I used another nickname. I am trying to void this nickname from the internet, and these obscure sites are the only ones still popping up.

I am trying to contact the sites (I have my doubts about their GDPR compliance), but I want to know what their background is in general. Only reason I can think of is some kind of mirror for countries where YouTube is blocked? But it sounds like a lot of work to embed every single YouTube video with comments.

Answer (score 0):

These sites just scrape YouTube and replace any instances of YouTube's ads with their own ads. That gives them the benefit of having the massive content library YouTube has without the drawback of actually having to host it or otherwise doing any actual work. There is a tiny "legitimate" usecase in that these sites sometimes allow access to YouTube in places where the government/boss has blocked it, but overall, they're just spam.